# difference between Date() in nodejs and in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

Why is it when i call Date() in nodejs i get the following weird output that i cant understand:

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d);
```

output in nodejs: 2022-08-28T14:47:09.877Z

output in browser: Sun Aug 28 2022 15:48:25 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

1- What is T14:47:09.877Z in the case of nodejs output?

2- What is the rational to provide a different implementation of date object in nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

This is a pretty common date format, you can get it using `toISOString`

EcmaScript doesn't specify how the date should look after using `toString` hence the difference. ISO format is much more useful for backend operations.

Comment: I recommend to change the link to English wiki instead of Polish

Comment: it's not only 'pretty common', but the only format that the ECMA262 spec specifies for Date.parse(). [21.4.1.15 Date Time String Format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format)

Comment: I have never seen any other time format used for frontend-backend communication for example.